# A Variable That Doesn't Overflow

Tags: java, overflow, long-integer

I've been working with some very big numbers lately, and it has gone to the extent where even my longs overflow. Is there any variable that never overflows?

Comment: `BigInteger` will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should use `BigInteger`, but is is a class type, not a variable.

`BigInteger bi = BigInteger.valueOf(num);`

Answer (score 2):

`BigInteger` solves the problem here.

> Immutable arbitrary-precision integers. All operations behave as if BigIntegers were represented in two's-complement notation (like Java's primitive integer types). BigInteger provides analogues to all of Java's primitive integer operators, and all relevant methods from java.lang.Math. Additionally, BigInteger provides operations for modular arithmetic, GCD calculation, primality testing, prime generation, bit manipulation, and a few other miscellaneous operations. ([Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html))

You can create `BigInteger` like so:

```
BigInteger int1 = new BigInteger("2");
BigInteger int2 = BigInteger.valueOf(4);

// However, because Java has no operator overloading, you have to do this.
// int3 would be 6.
BigInteger int3 = int1.add(int2);
```